# Is there a primitive type for DateTime in Bixby?

Tags: bixby

My model will optionally take a time in many utterances.

So examples...

add wet diaper.  <-------- assumes current time
add wet diaper at 4:00 PM
add bottle at noon

What would be the best way to model 4 PM/AM so that in my actions I can collect the time?

Comment: I thought of doing an enumeration (so I could handle words like noon ) for the hour, an int for the minute, then an enumeration for AM or PM. But, I was hoping there was some built-in resolution that could handle the different types of inputs for time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to define an action that accepts an optional input, and make sure the type is 'DateTimeExpression'.  In your NL training, you can say things like 'do this thing at 4PM' or 'do this thing'.  Both are valid because you made the date optional.  In your javascript, check to see if the user said a date.  If they did, use it.  If not, you can default to now. Refer to this [link](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/library.datetime#handling-dates-and-times-in-javascript) for grabbing the time from javascript.  The date api will parse dates to the device's local time by default (can be overridden).

**In your action**

`input (searchDate) {
      type (time.DateTimeExpression)
      min(Optional) max (One)
  }`

**In your javascript**

```
var currentTime = dates.ZonedDateTime.now().getDateTime();


if (searchDate)
     currentTime = //Grab the date from searchDate.
```

Use [this](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/library.datetime#handling-dates-and-times-in-javascript) for reference.

Comment: Thanks! That's a great response.

Comment: How do I actually import that time.DateTimeExpression? When I add that type to my action it tells me it's not able to find it.

Comment: It's an external capsule library.  Just add this to your capsule.bxb file: 
  More info here:  https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/library

Comment: No matter what I do the training phrase stays as "Not Learned". I have it showing up in the training console, but it never gets learned.

Comment: For anyone else.... I had an utterance of "do action at 4am". In the UI I was highlighting "at 4am" when I selected it as a date time expression. I switched it to highlight just "4am", and dropped the "at"  and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no primitive type DateTime, but there is a viv.time library you can use, and in fact there is viv.time.DateTimeExpression concept you can use.

viv.time.DateTimeExpression not only handles "4 AM" but also "tomorrow 4 AM", you can read more [here](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/library.datetime). I would say it is one of the most commonly used library concepts.